# creating linkable words without any plugin in the_content

Tags: wordpress

I have some idea, O will create 2 different variable on my functions.php. for example;

```
$words = array('text','text2','text3');
$urls = array('url.com','url2.com','url3.com');
```

Now I want to use this, with the the_content(); functions.
I found some plugin for this, like Automattic Seo Links etc. But I really don't need more configuration for this. I just want to some words linkable in the content area.

I tried it with `str_replace` method, but it didn't worked with gallery shout code, and some other shortcode setting.

Could anyone help me for this? Or got any idea?

---

Solved .

```
function replace_content($content)
{
$find = 
array(
  "word1",
  "word2",
  "word3",
  "word4",
);
$replace = 
array(
  "url.com",
  "url2.com",
  "url3.com",
  "url4.com",
  );      
$content = str_replace($find, $replace, $content);
return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content','replace_content');
```

Comment: Have you tried using Wordpress's hooks and filters?

Comment: Yes, @msbodetti. But when i use get_the_content and str_replace mathod, the shortcodes [gallery] [youtube] etc. didint work

Comment: But how are you calling the shortcodes with your arrays above? Because arrays dont create shortcodes...

Comment: use post->post_content; instead of the_content();

Comment: i will try it again than i hope i can fix it.

Comment: @Fatih Please add your code as an answer and accept it. The question is not the right place to add your answer!